# Unsupported redo log format (0). The redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9 deleting log files with a shutdown before the upgrade

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I did brew update mysql. It install version 8.0.19. Before doing the upgrade, I perform mysql.server stop. This is on MacOS 10.14.6. When I went to start the server again, it failed. The log file contained:

```
2020-02-05T04:48:02.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/yamadoshi.local.err'.
2020-02-05T04:48:02.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2020-02-05T04:48:02.853357Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1208
2020-02-05T04:48:02.860739Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-02-05T04:48:02.882261Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2020-02-05T04:48:02.952136Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013090] [InnoDB] Unsupported redo log format (0). The redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9
2020-02-05T04:48:02.952260Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2020-02-05T04:48:02.952921Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2020-02-05T04:48:02.953206Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-02-05T04:48:02.953338Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-02-05T04:48:02.955032Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  Homebrew.
2020-02-05T04:48:02.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/yamadoshi.local.pid ended
_______________________________________________________________________________
```

I found the same question here:

> If you have already installed MySQL and did not perform a slow shutdown using the
>
> innodb_fast_shutdown
>
> Flag, simply go to your MySQL directory
>
> /var/lib/mysql/
>
> And remove the log files (Do not do this if you need the table data in your database until you have backed up your database):
>
> ib_logfile0 ib_logfile1
>
> Back them up before if you need them again.

Given that I did do a shutdown, assuming it was the correct type, can I just delete the log files without loosing my data? I haven't made any changes to the tables in quite some time.

I was able to install mysql 5.6. I can get it to give the version number, but it errors with in a similar fashion as some of the file pointers are still pointing to 8.0.19 install.